# How do I check if a user (ObjectID) is a member of a Group (GroupName) in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How do I check if a user (ObjectID) is a member of a Group (GroupName) in Azure AD B2C?
I've got an IdToken and Accesstoken. I have authenticated. Now I am trying to access a resource.

I tried the below code but to no avail. The reference 'TokenCredentialAuthProvider' could not be found because I am using Microsoft.Graph V 5.2.30 and Microsoft.Graph.Core 3.0.10. Please be kind I am new to this.

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;

public async Task<bool> CheckUserGroupMembership(string userName, string groupName, string accessToken)
{
    // Create an authentication provider by passing in a DefaultAzureCredentialOptions object
    var authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions());

    // Create a GraphServiceClient instance with the authentication provider
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    // Create a request to get the user by name
    var userRequest = graphClient.Users.Request().Filter($"userPrincipalName eq '{userName}'").Select("id");

    // Send the request and get the response
    var userResponse = await userRequest.GetAsync();

    // Get the user ID if found, null otherwise
    string userId = userResponse.Count > 0 ? userResponse[0].Id : null;

    // If the user ID is null, return false
    if (userId == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create a request to get the group by name
    var groupRequest = graphClient.Groups.Request().Filter($"displayName eq '{groupName}'").Select("id");

    // Send the request and get the response
    var groupResponse = await groupRequest.GetAsync();

    // Get the group ID if found, null otherwise
    string groupId = groupResponse.Count > 0 ? groupResponse[0].Id : null;

    // If the group ID is null, return false
    if (groupId == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create a request to check the user's membership in the group
    var membershipRequest = new DirectoryObjectCheckMemberGroupsRequest(
        graphClient.Users[userId].Request().RequestUrl,
        graphClient,
        new List<string>() { groupId });

    // Send the request and get the response
    var membershipResponse = await membershipRequest.PostAsync();

    // Return true if the response contains the group ID, false otherwise
    return membershipResponse.Contains(groupId);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To check if a user is a member of a Group in Azure AD B2C, please use the below code:**

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            "TenantID",
            "ClientID",
            "ClientSecret"
        );

        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(
             new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }
        );

        var accessToken = (await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext)).Token;

        var userId = "UserID";
        var groupId = "GroupID";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/memberOf?$filter=id eq '{groupId}'");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The user with ID {userId} is a member of the group with ID {groupId}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The user with ID {userId} is not a member of the group with ID {groupId}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**You can also make use of `GraphServiceClient` like below:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        string tenantId = "TenantID";
        string clientId = "ClientID";
        string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
        string userId = "UserID";
        string groupId = "GroupID";

         var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

         var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);
        var result = await graphClient.Users[userId].MemberOf.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
        {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "id eq '98b9b13c-6f65-4ce6-ae8d-xxxx'";
        });

        if (result == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The user with ID {userId} is not a member of the group with ID {groupId}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The user with ID {userId} is a member of the group with ID {groupId}");
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

**Note** that: You have to make use of `GroupID` instead of `GroupName` as Group Name's are not unique.

Comment: Brilliantly done and well-explained. Thank you.